# Does excel for mac support xml maps?

Tags: microsoft-office, xml, export, xsd, office-for-mac

On PC, Since Office 2003, there is XML support through the **XML Maps** panel using XML Schema(XSD).

I can't seem to work my way around the Office for Mac website.

Does anyone know, **are XML Maps supported on the Mac version of Office** as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not at the moment it [seems](http://www.officeformac.com/ms/ProductForums/Excel/7364).